# Generate all dates between two dates in %Y-%m-%d-%H format in bash

Tags: bash, date, gnu

Using bash I want to generate all dates between, say, `2023-11-04-00` and `2023-11-06-00` where the format is `%Y-%m-%d-%H`. I have tried :

```
#!/bin/bash

d=2023-11-04
while [ "$d" != 2023-11-06 ]; do
        d=$(date -d "$d 1 hour")
        u=$(date -d "$d" +'%Y-%m-%d-%H')
        echo $u
done
```

It works but I get an infinite loop and can't quite figure out what is happening.

Comment: You aren't using the expected format when you change the value of `d`.

Comment: It means that `d` will never be exactly equal to the string `2023-11-06`. Do something like `echo "'$d'"` at the end of the loop to check this.

Comment: Of course I know that. I just wanted to provide a basic piece of code to give a context to the question. As you can see in the accepted answer, that was not trivial and I'm glad I did not loose a couple hours figuring this out, given my limited knowledge of bash. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than performing hazardous and non locale-agnostic date arithmetic, using a unix timestamp ensures consistent results

Using Bash grammar:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

start_date=2023-11-04
end_date=2023-11-06

start_ts=$(date -d "$start_date" +%s)
end_ts=$(date -d "$end_date" +%s)

for ((ts=start_ts; ts<=end_ts; ts+=3600))
do printf '%(%Y-%m-%d-%H)T\n' "$ts"
done
```

Using POSIX-shell grammar:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

start_date=2023-11-04
end_date=2023-11-06

start_ts=$(date -d "$start_date" +%s)
end_ts=$(date -d "$end_date" +%s)

ts=$start_ts
while [ "$ts" -le "$end_ts" ]
do
  date -d "@$ts" +'%Y-%m-%d-%H' 
  ts=$((ts + 3600))
done
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ts+=86400`?

Comment: @user1934428 if you want to add a day, yes

Comment: Right. I was confused by the title of the question, which suggests just _dates_, but I now notice that the OP actually wants granularity by hour.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at what `$d` actually looks like:

```bash
$ d=2023-11-04
$ d=$(date -d "$d 1 hour")
$ echo "$d"
Sat Nov  4 01:00:00 AM EDT 2023
```

Oh. That's not a string that's ever going to be equal to `2023-11-06`.

Let's see if we can fix that:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

d=2023-11-04
while [ "$(date -d "$d" +'%Y-%m-%d')" '<' 2023-11-06 ]; do
        d=$(date -d "$d 1 hour")
        u=$(date -d "$d" +'%Y-%m-%d-%H')
        echo $u
done
```

Much better.

Comment: You are a genius thanks

Comment: Does not work on other locales

Comment: @LeaGris: Why? Shouldn't  `date -d "$d" +'%Y-%m-%d'` due to the explicit format specification  guarantee, that the comparision works independent on the locale?

Comment: @user1934428 `d=$(date -d "$d 1 hour")` causes `d` to contain a locale formatted date that is incompatible with the 1 in fr_FR locale.